# Accessing Electron API from Angular Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I'm looking to load a locally saved video file via electron and play it in my angular component. For this, I have the loadLocalFile function that I expose in order to avoid setting nodeIntegration to true. I still get this Security Warning :

> This renderer process has either no Content Security Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of this app to unnecessary security risks.

I do not have a renderer.js file as I'm using Angular. How am I meant to access my electronAPI in my Angular?

My Preload.js contains the following, which I want to call from my Angular component:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  loadLocalFile: (event, filePath) => {
    if (filePath === undefined) {
      console.log("No file selected");
      return;
    }

    dialog.showOpenDialog((filePath) => {
      // fileNames is an array that contains all the selected
      if (filePath === undefined) {
        console.log("No file selected");
        return;
      }

      fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
          return;
        }

        // Change how to handle the file content
        console.log("The file content is : " + data);
      });
    });
  },
});
```

My app.module.ts conains the following:

```
export interface IElectronAPI {
  loadLocalFile: (event: Event | null, path: string) => Promise<void>;
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electronAPI: IElectronAPI;
  }
}
```

in my Angular Component I access the Api with:

```
window.electronAPI.loadLocalFile(null, "/path/to/my/video");
```

How are you meant to implement the electron API access from your Angular component? A service would probably work well, but I couldn't find or come up with a working example that isn't broken by the removal of certain imports

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngx-electron. which helps to you calling Electron APIs from the Renderer Process easier.you can easily able to use into Angular project. but I am not sure able that it will helps to read video file or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've already looked at ngx-electron. Unfortunately it doesn't work with Electron 15, as it doesn't export a Remote Module, which ngx-electron depends on.

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting:

Error: node_modules/ngx-electron/lib/electron.service.d.ts:17:31 - error TS2694: Namespace 'Electron.CrossProcessExports' has no exported member 'Remote'.

17     readonly remote: Electron.Remote;

Comment: you can use   "@electron/remote" for remote. then import it like add as electron services.

import * as remote from '@electron/remote';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ElectronService {
remote: typeof remote;
get isElectron(): boolean {
    return !!(window && window.process && window.process.type);
  }
constructor() {
    // Conditional imports
    if (this.isElectron) {
   this.remote = window.require('@electron/remote');
    }
}